# Find all same words in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to catch if to characters in same word located like this : TT,tt,ee,dd then print True

```
list = ["ttest", "teest", "tesst", "testt"]
```

How can I do that.

thx.

Comment: please explain little bit more..

Comment: `x == x` will always `True`. I suggest you take out a piece of paper and pen and do this by hand. If don't understand the process, you can't translate it into code.

Comment: Please don't change the question after you posted it!

Comment: Also, "identical when lowercased" is quite a lot simpler and straightforward than "identical when duplicated adjacent characters removed" or even "within edit distance <= 1" - these two don't really belong in the same question. Solve the first, google the second, then maybe come back and post a new, specific question if there's a specific problem you need help with.

Comment: Your question is totally changed after your edit. I flagged it as unclear what you asking

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ["test", "Test", "TEST", "tEst"]

print (set([x.lower() for x in list1]))
```

Using `lower()` and convert the list to a set, so if there is any same string, it will return the one of them.

Comment: I mean if to characters in same word located like this : TT,tt,ee then print True

Comment: @davai You said in your question `I'm trying to catch all same words in list`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework assignment. My first thought is to use a hashset with lower or upper for the first problem, and a for loop across the chars of each string for the second prob. Keep track of the prior char and check against current char. If not same set prior char to current char and continue to the next.